# Fogra39 (CMYK color space) to CIEXYZ

Tags: colors, rgb, equation, cmyk

I am wondering whether exist a way how to transform colors of specific CMYK color space (lets say FOGRA39) to CIEXYZ.
I know how to sRGB to CIEXYZ, as there are dozens of 'how-to' on internet.
But I never found similar **transformation equation for FOGRA39** (or any other printing color space). 
Have somebody experiences to share them with me? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

These colorspace transformations are not described as formulae but as (mostly) look-up tables in ICC profiles (.icc files).

**Longer answer**

The color values in some color spaces are related to other color spaces via relatively simple closed-form expressions. Well known examples are the relation between XYZ and Lab, and the relation between sRGB and XYZ that you mentioned. Often the corresponding transformation formulae are obtained from color-theoretical considerations.

On the other hand, the color spaces corresponding to actual or idealised printing processes (such as [FOGRA39](http://www.color.org/fogra39.xalter)) are characterised by performing actual printing experiments. This is done by printing a large number of different color patches under controlled circumstances on the device that is being profiled (a printing press for example), and measuring the color of the resulting printed patches with a photo spectrometer.

These measurements do *not* yield a simple formula for conversion between color spaces, but instead a table of a large number of pairs of color values: the known amount of ink printed (e.g. CMYK) versus measured color. This color profile table is then typically stored in a standardised (file) format: the [ICC profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile). Here is an [ICC profile for FOGRA39](http://www.color.org/registry/Coated_Fogra39L_VIGC_300.xalter). (Actually, while look-up tables are an important part of typical ICC profiles, ICC profiles also support parametric curves and matrix transformations to do colorspace conversions.)

For most users, the ICC file format is too complicated to parse and interpret, and color management too cumbersome to implement oneself from scratch. If you need to perform color conversion to or from a color space represented by an ICC profile, one typically uses the color management facilities offered by the operating system, or a by third-party library.

Virtually all color management systems (CMS) in use today have support for ICC profiles, and their APIs have support for color conversion using ICC profiles.

The major platforms Mac and Windows have their own color management systems and APIs that you can use, and on Linux open source solutions (such as [little cms](http://www.littlecms.com)) are available as well. The specifics however depend on the platform one targets, and programming language one intends to use.

Comment: Thank you for a complex answer. My reason to know the transformation equations is to develop a tool to allow cartographers prepare color schemes of a specified color distance between shades. (It is more or less theoretical work). I did it already for sRGB [http://eyetracking.upol.cz/color/](http://eyetracking.upol.cz/color/) and I wished to do it also for Fogra. But still dont know how... :-(

Comment: Do you need a platform independent solution? Or does a solution specifically for Mac/Windows/Linux suffice (if so, what platform)?

Comment: Not sure, whether I understand why you are asking about platform :) But I would say - independent solution...

Comment: I mean does your tool run on Windows only? Or on Mac only? Linux only? Or do you need a tool that runs on several operating systems? (I'm asking because that will influence what API to use to handle the ICC profile.)

Comment: Ah, I would prefer to device independent solution. Now it is done with PHP, thus available via any web browser...